# Leadbord database

Tags: android, sql

This is actually the first time that i try to use a SQL database on android. So i hope you can help me with it.
I am current working on a leadbord in our game and wanted to write the Communicationclass for it but i got in troubles with it. i used http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html for it. and this is how my Db Helper class looks like

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String TABLE_LEADBOARD = "leadboard";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_LEVEL = "level";
public static final String COLUMN_KILLPOINTS = "killpoints";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "leadboard.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database creation sql statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
    + TABLE_LEADBOARD + "(" + COLUMN_ID
    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_NAME
    + " text,"+ COLUMN_LEVEL + " integer," +COLUMN_KILLPOINTS + " integer);";

public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LEADBOARD);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

i wrote a simple element that has the 4 Fields and getter and setter

```
public class LeadbordElement {
    private long id;
    private int level;
    private int killPoints;
    private String name;
```

my connection class looks like this now

```
public class DatabaseCommunication {
    // Database fields
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
    // all columns for the query
    private String[] allColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LEVEL,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_KILLPOINTS };

    public DatabaseCommunication(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    /**
     * Save element to database
     * 
     * @author Benjamin M. 17.01.2013
     * @param element
     */
    public void addLeadbordElement(LeadbordElement element) {
        this.open();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME, element.getName());
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LEVEL, element.getLevel());
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_KILLPOINTS, element.getKillPoints());
        database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_LEADBOARD, null, values);
        this.close();
    }

    /**
     * Methode to get a Vektor of elements
     * 
     * @author Benjamin M. 17.01.2013
     */
    public Vector<LeadbordElement> getTop10() {
        this.open();
        // should return ordert by killpoints
        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_LEADBOARD,
                allColumns, null, null, null, null,
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_KILLPOINTS + " DESC");

        Vector<LeadbordElement> elements = new Vector<LeadbordElement>();

        //creating the vector of elements
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            elements.add(this.createElement(cursor));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        this.close();
        return elements;
    }

    /**
     * Methode to create a LeadbordElement out of the cursor
     * 
     * @author Benjamin M. 17.01.2013
     * @param cursor
     * @return
     */
    private LeadbordElement createElement(Cursor cursor) {
        LeadbordElement element = new LeadbordElement();
        element.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        element.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        element.setLevel(cursor.getInt(2));
        element.setKillPoints(cursor.getInt(3));
        return element;
    }
}
```

But this acutally does not work. I cant get the top10 of it like this, and i dont get the misstake of it. Well actually i can create the DatabaseCommunication and i can add an element. not sure if it really get added to a database. But i cant get those back.
It says there is no Column: level: , while compiling: select _id .......

At least i got a textview and want to display the elements there.

Thanks if you can help!

Errorlog:

```
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14110)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     ... 11 more
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: level: , while compiling: SELECT _id, name, level, killpoints FROM leadboard ORDER BY killpoints DESC
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1449)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1405)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1485)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at control.database.DatabaseCommunication.getTop10(DatabaseCommunication.java:61)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at com.main.MainActivity.startLeadbord(MainActivity.java:178)
01-17 19:04:35.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i *think* i see it...pls add a (missing) whitespace after COLUMN_LEVEL and COLUMN_KILLPOINTS

from...

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
    + TABLE_LEADBOARD + "(" + COLUMN_ID
    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_NAME
    + " text,"+ COLUMN_LEVEL + "integer," +COLUMN_KILLPOINTS + "integer);";
```

to....

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
    + TABLE_LEADBOARD + "(" + COLUMN_ID
    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_NAME
    + " text,"+ COLUMN_LEVEL + " integer," +COLUMN_KILLPOINTS + " integer);";
```

Comment: added the whitespaces but actually did not help. I edit the log i get from it logging cat

Comment: can you run the sqlite3 command from `adb shell` and query the sqlite_master table. it'll show you what the REAL table definition is. e.g. from a command prompt, enter `adb shell`. from there cd to `/data/data/<your package>/databases` then enter `sqlite3 xxxx.db` where xxxx is your database name. then run a query.

Comment: sure. just open a terminal window (Command Prompt in Windows..Terminal in *nix) and follow the directions above. it's EZ! the query you want to run is `select * from sqlite_master where tbl_name='yourTableName';` It'll show you the structure of the REAL table. hopefully it'll then make a fix obvious.

Comment: you need to be local to your database...or perhaps you could enter `sqlite3 /data/data/<package>/databases/xxxxx.db`. worth a shot.

Comment: I just dont get it how to locate the database. I did run the sqlite3 out of the toolfolder from the sdk

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22928/discussion-between-david-m-and-benjamin)

Comment: Actually recreating after adding the whitespaces helped! Thank you so much!

Comment: you must have double-added the rows. when you DROPed the table all the data would have been deleted as well...when do you add data? each time the app is run (not good) or only when the table is created? or ?? you should spend some time in sqlite3 with your table. it will be very enlightening (it would tell you whether or not there are duplicate rows in it or not (might be a coding issue!)

Comment: i actually found it. i add them at the end when they touch to leave the game. and i did not catch the down AND up touch. so it got added twice